# stream .pdf error

Tags: c++, ifstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert a file (.txt,.pdf..) into a stream file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229774/convert-a-file-txt-pdf-into-a-stream-file)

```
std::string fil= "/home/sensor.pdf";

std::ifstream t(fil.c_str());

if (t)
{
    string res;
    string line;
    while (getline(t, line, '\n'))
    {
        res=res+line;
    }
    std::string p;
    p=(((reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *> (res.c_str())),res.size()));
    std::string f_data=p;

    char *token = strtok( const_cast<char*>(fil.c_str() ), "/" );
    std::string name;
    std::vector<int> values;

    while ( token != NULL )
    {                       
        name=token;

        token = strtok( NULL, "/" );
    }
    std::strig f_name=name;
}
```

When I try to load the .pdf file I have an error "unable to read. PDF IS DAMAGED". WHY? This code works for .txt files and .cpp files. I've tested it. I am currently working in ubuntu c++ code. I've also used the base_64 encode/decode because this was the request.

Comment: Do you have permissions to read that file?

Comment: Also you probably shouldn't try to read binary files without the binary flag and with `getline`. Or with `c_str()`

Comment: yes i have permision to read the file. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @sunset what is the _exact_ error message you get?

Comment: @sunset also what are you trying to do? You're probably doing about it wrong.

Comment: I am trying to put in a  string a pdf file.

Comment: @sunset you can't modify a binary file like that, you're going about this completely wrong. You'll need to find a PDF library and use that.

Comment: Two things come to mind: 1) not opening the file in binary mode might cause you to read the wrong data. 2) reading with `getline` discards linebreaks.

Comment: You are aware that pdf files are not plain text? they have a very specific format that has to be followed? See http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/adobe_supplement_iso32000_1.pdf

Comment: You did not really provide much more information as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229774/convert-a-file-txt-pdf-into-a-stream-file

Comment: is there a way I can solve this problem? And also Is there a way I can change getline in order to have the linebreaks?

Comment: @sunset: off topic, code should be [indented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) for readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/libharu/

I saw it recommended in a few different places, including a couple different SO questions - but all they gave was the link.

It's a free, open-souce library for PDF reading.  It probably isn't as easy as you want, but I think its as easy as you're gonna get and its free.

It's also multi-platform so should work on UNIX and windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening with:

```
ifstream file ("/home/sensor.pdf", ios::in|ios::binary);
```

Comment: ok. I am going to add this to my code. What should I use besides getline in order to leave the linebreaks? Have any suggesion? THX. Appreciate

Comment: the error is still the same. PDF File is damaged.:(.

Comment: @sunset like I said, you are _doing it wrong_, and nothing short of a specially made PDF library will help you.

Comment: @sunset see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58730/open-source-pdf-library-for-c-c-application

Comment: Okay, if it still says damaged then my attempt didn't help - sorry about that.

Comment: i need a free and easy way to do this

Comment: @sunset did you read the link I gave you? w00te apparently did.